# How do I replace the bulb in this enclosed bathroom ceiling light?

Tags: lighting, bulb

There is a small groove between the white and black sections, but it doesn't come loose with slotting a screwdriver in the groove.

[image]

Comment: Does it unscrew (the glass)?  Or even turn a little and lower?

Comment: No, the black part moves a little from side to side, but the white plastic doesn't move at all!

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is a spring clip.  It might just pull down and release.  Shouldn't take more than a few pounds of force.  Pull the plastic, not the black part, though the clip could be on either side.

Comment: I'd put money on twisting.

Comment: Have one person hold the black base and another turn the plastic.

Comment: **How many DIY'rs does it take to change a light bulb**. *I agree, turning or twisting the white cover while holding the black base should be the way*.

Answer (score 2):

These fixtures usually have a ["bayonet" mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount), requiring a partial turn, perhaps just a few degrees, and then pulling straight down on the plastic cover. After years, it may require a wiggle or two to break it loose.